# Are there any variable length hash functions available for Python?

Tags: python, hash

I am looking for a hash function that can generate a digest of a specified bit-size for a cryptographic signature scheme. A related question (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/are-there-hash-algorithms-with-variable-length-output) on the Cryptography SE specifies that algorithms exist for this particular purpose.
Are there any Python libraries that I can use for this?

Currently, my scheme just pads a SHA-256 output to the desired size. I also have tried the Python SHA3 library - pysha3 1.0.2, however, it has a few predefined digest sizes that can be used.

I want a hashing function which can take in the desired digest size as a parameter and accordingly hashes a message (if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Extendable output function (XOF) can be used to obtain a digest of a given size. From Wikipedia:

> Extendable-output functions (XOFs) are cryptographic hashes which can output an arbitrarily large number of random-looking bits.

One of the function provided under SHA-3 includes the SHAKE128 and SHAKE256 functions. They follow from the general properties of the [sponge construction](https://keccak.team/sponge_duplex.html). A sponge function can generate an arbitrary length of output. The 128 and 256 in their names indicates its maximum security level (in bits), as described in Sections A.1 and A.2 of [FIPS 202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf).

In python, first [install](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html) the PyCryptodome library:

```py
pip install pycryptodome
```

A hash of say 20 bytes can be generated as follows:

```py
from Crypto.Hash import SHAKE256
from binascii import hexlify
shake = SHAKE256.new()
shake.update(b'Some data')
print hexlify(shake.read(20))
```

Further references on SHAKE256 and SHA3:
[Link 1](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/shake256.html)
[Link 2](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.202.pdf)

Comment: Is it possible to generate a hash of 20 bytes with a public key, and then verify it is valid with a private key ?

Answer (score 3):

As a cursory answer: You might be interested in the inbuilt [Blake2 function in hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#blake2) in python 3.6+.

It only outputs up to 64 bytes, but is ["faster than MD5, SHA-1, SHA-2, and SHA-3, yet is at least as secure as the latest standard SHA-3"](https://blake2.net/).

Hopefully this is long enough and you don't need external libraries!